# Are there statistics on how many people from certain ethnic groups will be admitted if only standardized test scores are included?

Tags: discrimination

The question is for any country any universities or high school or any education or certification. So if you now that university A have say, 20% Asian students, and if they use only test scores, say 80% of their students will be Asians. So if you know any such info that's a legitimate answer for this question.

A sample is that the best high school in US had 73% Asian students and is lowering it to 54%.

https://www.wsj.com/articles/a-pta-purge-of-asians-11626128073

So basically I want answers with clear number. If we just use standardized tests, this much people from this group attend. If we put "effort for diversity" then we got this much.

For example, I've heard that engineering department in Berkelely has 80% Asian students when they are color blind and don't discriminate against Asians. On the other hand, other universities discriminate against Asians and have lower admission for Asian students.

The thing is that statement is a bit controversial. Harvard, for example, could argue that they don't "discriminate" Asians but just take into account holistic factors like race or diversity and stuffs. Conservatives would say that holistic factor is just subjective and an excuse for diversity.

So there is no way to know whether any universities discriminate against Asians or not because the definition of "discriminate" is vague.

If counting only on standardized test scores, what percentage of admitted students will be Asians?

The same goes for public universities in Indonesia. There are rumors, almost open secrets, that chineses are discriminated to go to public university in Indonesia. If there is no discrimination against Chinese, what percentage of students in Indonesian's public university will be chinese?

What percentage of Singapore university students are chinese (with or without discrimination)?

**Note:** What I mean by objective criteria is a criteria that can be measured objectively. For example, a school may use eye color, or armpit hair length to decides admission. It's pretty obvious for everyone that it doesn't have any effect whatsoever on whether students with certain eye color or certain armpit hair length will be more successful at college. However, we can also agree that tests for eye color and armpit hair length can be done objectively and comparably.

So if some schools use say, armpit hair length to admit students and somehow that changes some groups end up being more or less likely to be admitted that would count.

Grade in high schools, for example, however, is not objectively comparable. An A in some high schools may be equivalent of an F in other schools.

This question does not question whether SAT is a good predictor of academic performance. Some say yes. Some say no. I don't care about it. All I want to know is if schools use, say, SAT only, how many asians are admitted, and how many are not, which schools, do you have data, etc.

If they have other standardized tests, like armpit hairlength, or being able to do 3 points shot in basket ball, that'll count too.

Comment: There is debate as to how objective standardised tests are. One of the best predictors for SAT score is family income, for example (how many prep courses your parents can afford to send you to).

Comment: As asked, your question is too broad, and I agree with the comment by user141592 that "objective" test scores are hardly that.

Comment: One of the best predictors for SAT score is family income. Still, whatever the score is we can objectively compare with one another. The subjective part is whether the test is suitable for admissions. However, the scoring itself is objective and comparable. That's what I mean. Maybe I should simplify to based on Math tests?

Comment: If not test scores if you have any other objective standards that'll be fine too. How should I modify the question?

Comment: Question changed to standardized test. It seems that the word "objective" is too politically charged. I am not questioning if standardized test SHOULD be the only thing used to measure students' admission. In fact, I don't even think so. A reasonable school wouldn't admit a mass murderer psychopaths with high standardized score. I am asking if we only use test scores, how would different groups or race change their admission rate.

Comment: @user141592: or...not. Our eldest daughter got 2400 on the SAT (when the SAT had the extra "written" component or whatever it was called). We never sent her to a single prep course. Sometimes being smart and well-read is sufficient.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica ...That's a nice anecdote. "Predictor" refers to the statistical sense, where when you look at a population of say everyone in the US who takes the test a given year, high scores tend to share a specific trait. Individual exceptions like your daughter do not disprove a general trend.

Comment: @user141592 I'm quite sure that the parent's educational history and upbringing is also one of the best predictor for family income - something that is obviously passed on to their children. You make it look like you can _buy_ your way up, without studying and _learning_ things.

Comment: @pipe You do still have to learn, but money can certainly _buy_ you the _opportunity_ to study and learn things.

Comment: @user141592 He's still correct in some sense. The parent's educational history and upbringing helped them be successful financially, and they can use that finance to help their children succeed.

Comment: @Ray actually I think this is the biggest point. There seem to be families who don't own a single book (not out of poverty) and mock their children for reading. Somehow the parents don't end up wealthy and the kids not very well read.

Comment: You write "This question does not question whether SAT is a good predictor of academic performance", but throughout the post you assert that universities are discriminating against Asian applicants and seem to equate this with how they treat SAT scores. At the very least you are sending mixed signals about your beliefs. You also correlate diversity with discrimination, whereas in the real world the opposite is true: lack of diversity is a result of preferences (hopefully unconscious) towards majority groups. I recommend that you reexamine your base assumptions.

Comment: @user141592 but prep course attendance is only a modest predictor of scores.  Most of the benefit of parental wealth and education comes from factors other than test prep, and in fact it can be seen in kindergarten children, who start with a performance gap that persists throughout.  Another factor is subtle (or flagrant) cultural bias in tests: a former boss of mine told of a multiple choice question with pictures of four men: "which of these men is going to work?"  The correct answer, of course, was the guy in the business suit, not the one in shirt sleeves or the one with a hard hat.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about any one particular school? I suspect that these results will vary dramatically based on location and what sort of school you're talking about. For example, a science and engineering school in the U.S. will attract more Asian students without implementing discriminatory measures against them than will, say, a liberal arts college. And one in an area with a large Asian immigrant community would probably attract even more. Even in a small college town in TN, though, more than half of my graduate school classmates were Asian.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see any way this question could be answered objectively: (1) there is no well-defined distinction between asian vs. non-asian; (2) the sample of students who apply to an institution is usually unknown; (3) the question asks for any country, so... even in Asia? (4) Higher education is highly international especially in the US, so the applications from foreign countries have to be taken into account, knowing that China and India have large populations... Unless there's some serious study which took care of controlling everything, it's way too complex for PoliticsSE imho.

Comment: Additionally the question asks for potentially every school/university in the world, this is not at all the kind of question which fits the SE format.

Comment: Basically if you know any particular schools, that say admit more asian students based on test alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kansas State University is a university that [guarantees places based on a SAT score of 1060](https://blog.prepscholar.com/colleges-with-guaranteed-admission-based-on-sat-and-act-scores).

[Kansas State has 1.7% Asian-American students](https://www.collegefactual.com/colleges/kansas-state-university/student-life/diversity/chart-undergraduate-racial-ethnic-diversity.html), slightly underrepresented compared to the State as a whole which [is about 2.95% Asian](https://worldpopulationreview.com/states/kansas-population).  Note that "Asian" includes many different ethnicities.

Alternative approach:

The SAT test has a standard deviation of 211 and the [means for different ethic groups are known](https://nces.ed.gov/fastfacts/display.asp?id=171)

This means (assume a normal distribution) that 78% of Asian students would reach the required standard for K-State, compared with 50% of non-asian students.  If 2.95% of applicants were Asian, then from 100,000 applicants, 2300 would be successful Asian applicants and 48525 would be successful non-Asian applicants.  This would be 4.5% of the school.

The difference (1.7% v. 4.5%) is principally due to Asian students not applying to K-State, for various reasons.

Comment: Why would an ambitious student of *any* ethnicity apply to a college which admits *anybody* who meets a low-threshold criterion?  The obvious conclusion is that Asian students have above-average *ambition,* whatever their *ability* might be.

Comment: Do they track applications from asians, or just population of students vs population of state?

Comment: @alephzero Yes absolutely.

Comment: @jon You  can repeat the analysis with the demographics of the USA.  K-state tracks applications of *Asian-Americans*  (international students are grouped separately) SAT tracks the test results by ethnicity, international students may not be using SAT based entries.

Comment: This is a great answer. This is the kind of answer I want. However, Kansas State University seems a very low rank university. Any sample of high rank universities?

Answer (score 10):

Your question cannot be answered because **there are no objective measurements** of academic achievement or potential.

In Germany, where I live, there have been much-debated studies where teachers were asked to grade papers and it turned out that the name of the fictitious student had a measurable impact on the grade (here the brief [summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevinism) in the English wikipedia). One might think that computer-administered tests might avoid this bias, but computers need training data. See this [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2016/06/10/google-faulted-for-racial-bias-in-image-search-results-for-black-teenagers/) on problematic google results. Both questions and accepted answers might be biased towards or against a cultural or ethnic group. (Who discovered America? "Columbus" is a very eurocentric answer.)

And since we're on Politics SE, keep in mind that the purpose of schools and universities is **not only the transmission of academic skills**. These institution are also used for the transmission of the values and traditions of the society in question. Whose values, exactly? Well, that's where bias comes in. And even academic skills cannot be defined without cultural value judgements. Do the tests focus on memorization or reasoning ability? Are students expected to apply values during their reasoning or just "hard" logic?

Comment: I am not asking for objective measurement of academic potential. In other word, if a school do standardized test in swahili language, or eye color for admission, we can all agree that it's very irrelevant on academic potential. However, we can also agree that eye color can be tested objectively.

Comment: If the American/German universities somehow discriminate based on hidden cultural bias, how come that _asians_ outcompete the native population? I don't think this answers the question, just tries to deflect the underlying question.

Comment: @pipe, which Asian minority in Germany are you talking about? The Kazhaks? The Chinese? The Vietnamese? And yes, I'm trying to "deflect" the question because it poses exam scores as some sort of objective measure, which they objectively aren't.

Comment: @pipe It could be that asians study what kind of answers are expected, allowing them to bypass the cultural bias. Similar to how one would study how to answer specific questions in a job interview.

Comment: "Who discovered America? "Columbus" is a very eurocentric answer." Clearly the correct answer is "Lief Ericson". ;)

Comment: @Ray But what's stopping other cultures from doing the same, to gain entry to the university they want?

Comment: @pipe that's where opinions come in. On one side, you have people saying that the test taker should have just given the answer that was expected. On the other side, you have people saying that the test taker was not at fault and the test should have accommodated them better.

Comment: I modified the question of what I mean by objective criteria. I mean a criteria that can be measured objectively. It doesn't mean that the criteria correctly predict whether the students are suitable for the university.

Comment: In other words armpit length test would be an objective criteria even though it has no relevancy whatsoever. Obviously no school use that. But it's objective. We can measure, we can agree what it measures. SAT tests is also reasonably objective criteria. Grade school grade is not because you can't compare A in one university with A in another. Race? You can't really ascertain a person's race, especially mixed people and using race would be how would I say it? Discrimination?

Comment: "there are no objective measurements of academic achievement or potential" [citation needed] that's just a ridiculous claim. There are countless objective ways of measuring academic achievement and potential, you may say there is no completely flawless method, but many effective methods exist. e.g. https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/tests/iq/culture-fair-iq-test

Comment: The test you link is *terribly* biased towards pattern recognition. Which *is* a bias towards a kind of geek culture ...